# Update viewdata on button clicks

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<div id="newApplication" class="invisible">
     <form id="frmnewApplication" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <ul class="formone">
                <li>
                    <label class="labelone">
                        Name:</label>
                    <%--    <input type="text" id="ApplicationName" class="inputtext validate[required]" />--%>
                    <%= Html.DropDownList("ApplicationName", ViewData["AppList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>
                </li>
```

This is my div. I am fetching the values from `viewdata["AppList"]`. My dropdown is fetching the values from ViewData in pageload only even though I am updating my viewdata in other controller methods it is not updating the viewdata. Plz help.
This is the jquery method

```
function updateDropdown() {
            $("#ApplicationName").html("");
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/Shielding/AjaxGetDdlList",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        alert("Something went wrong. Please try again;");
                    }
                    else {
                        for (group in data) {
                            var newOption = $("<option></option>").attr("value", data[group].ShieldFirewallApplicationId).html(data[group].ShieldFirewallApplicationName);
                            alert(data[group].ShieldFirewallApplicationName);
                            $("#ApplicationName").append(newOption);

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

This is the controller method:

```
public ActionResult AjaxGetDdlList()
{
    return Json(ShieldingRep.GetAllApplications());
}
```

Comment: add your controller method code and name of this view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use tempdata. try to use viewmodels approach you may get help from this [link](http://www.billsternberger.net/asp-net-mvc/dynamically-populate-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: I did the same. I am sending the jquery function and controller method. Its not working. Please help

Comment: show your controller code update the view code if you have made any changes

Comment: I updated the code. I wrote the controller code there. plz check and help me.

Comment: Initially you are filling your dropdown with viewdata and in updatedropdown you haven't use it you are again fetching it back from remote source and i am guessing that data still unchanged

Comment: Try to follow tutorial from http://www.mikeyd.com.au/2009/08/22/dynamically-populate-a-selectdrop-down-list-using-aspnet-mvc-jquery-and-json/

Comment: no there is another method which will change the viewdata and I am calling updatedropdown there I also checked business layer there is a change in data.

Comment: I made a ajax call to method in controller AjaxGetDdlList() which will give the updated data. My ajax call gives me json data which is updated. But the data is not reflected in dropdown.

Comment: GetAllApplications looks culprit place break pint and see if that method returning you the updated data. Your changes are not committed in your data store and you r getting the old data

Comment: alert(data[group].ShieldFirewallApplicationName); I written an alert in updatedropdown() method which is showing the data correctly. But my dropdown is not getting bind with new data

Comment: Check the dropdownlist ID or try to start as fresh and try to follow the tutorial step by step

Answer (score 0):

Viewdata isn't persisted between calls. The problem will be found in your controller.